# Download link or View link to a file

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

i have a list of document from my models, one of the fields is a path to the url. how can i make a button such that when i click it, it opens the file.
I have tried some methods but it didn't work well
Thanks

This is the html

```
{% for document in document_lists_doc %}
                      <tr>
                        <th>{{forloop.counter}}</th>
                        <th>{{document.date}}</th>
                        <th>{{document.name}}</th>
                        <th>{{document.url}}</th>
                        <th>{{document.memo}}</th>
                      </tr>
                      {% endfor %}
```

This is the Model

```
class PurchaseOrderDocument(models.Model):
po_number = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
date = models.DateField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
url = models.FileField(upload_to='static/files/', null=True, max_length=500)
memo = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

[kindly check the image, i will like that path to be a link to open the file when clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReRSt.png)

Answer (score 0):

instead of just printing the URL, make it a hyperlink with  tag.

```
<th><a target='_blank' href = {{document.url}}>View File</a></th>
```

If you want the file to be opened in the same tab - Remove target = "_blank" from  tag.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work so I used this method. <th><a target='_blank' href = "/{{document.url}}/">View File</a></th>. This worked a little but I got a page not found error. I have also configured my status files properly and the rest. Can't figure out Why it isn't working

Comment: Can you tell me what URL you are getting when you click the view file link?

Comment: This is the link i get after doing that but i get page not found error

"/static/files/Smart_App_-_Requirements_-_Phase_1_-_v2.pdf"

Comment: It working already thanks

i noticed the part was the issue

The correct path should have been something like "http://localhost:5000/media/static/files/file.pdf" but media was ommited there, i had to do that manually

Do you perhaps have a better way of going about that